# Maximize $\sum\limits_{k =1}^n x_k (1 - x_k)^2$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, constraints, tangent-line-method

Given problem for maximizing
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k =1}^n x_k (1 - x_k)^2\rightarrow \max\\
&\sum_{k =1}^n x_k = 1,\\
&x_k \ge 0, \; \forall k \in 1:n.
\end{align}

**My attempt**: first of all i tried AM-GM, or we can just say, that $x_k (1 - x_k)^2 \le x_kx_k^2 =x_k^3$, but now we got just sum of cubes. Can we say, that $\sum\limits_{k =1}^n x_k^3 \le \sum\limits_{k =1}^n x_k,$ because $x_i \le 1$ and get our maximum - 1?
It looks very easy, but i suppose i'm wrong

Comment: Is there a reason you are using inequalities yielding upper bounds to try and maximize this function? This seems more like a job for calculus and Lagrange multipliers. Solving for $n = 2,3,4$ seems to imply that the maximizer is at $x_k = 1/n$ for all $k$

Comment: Remember that the maximum can be achieved. What you have found is an upper bound. But is it the least upper bound? E.g perhaps the sum can be bounded by 0.99?

Comment: @whpowell96 yes it's a problem from my optimization course, where i need to use inequalities:)

Comment: @CalvinLin ok, i unerstood, then i need to find at least upper bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ we get a value $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, 
\begin{align}
\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k(1-x_k)^2&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}-x_k(1-x_k)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n(1-nx_k)(n^2x_k^2-n(2n-1)x_k+(n-1)^2) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n\left((1-nx_k)(n^2x_k^2-n(2n-1)x_k+(n-1)^2)-(1-nx_k)(n^2-4n+3)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n(1-nx_k)^2(2n-2-nx_k)\geq0\text{ for any } n\geq2.
\end{align}
For $n=1$ we have $x_1=1$ and $$x_1(1-x_1)^2=0=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2},$$
which says that $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}$ is the answer.

Comment: So, $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}, or \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}$ is the answer? I got the second answer

Comment: @Juicer The answer is $n\cdot\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}.$ Check please better your computations.

Comment: i mean in the first line of your answer you say 'we get a value $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}$', then you say 'we'll prove it's the max value'

Comment: @Juicer It was typo. I fixed.

Comment: just one more question. In third line of equations you're just exclude $-(1 - nx_k)(n^2 - 4n + 3)$, is it because the first multiplier always positive, while second mult is turning somehow to negative value - we got general positive member, so we can exclude it since it plays no role?

Comment: @Juicer Yes, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(1-nx_k)(n^2-4n+3)=0.$ because $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k=1.$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the method of [Lagrange multiplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

You are trying to maximize
$$f = \sum_{k =1}^n x_k (1 - x_k)^2$$

subject to 
$$\sum_{k =1}^n x_k = 1$$

You have that
$$f_{x_k} = \lambda g_{x_k} \to 3x_k^2 - 4x_k + 1 = \lambda$$ is valid for all $x_k$. We can solve for $x_k$ to get that $$x_k = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{1+3\lambda}}{3}$$

Since $x_k$ must be positive, we have that $$x_k = \frac{2 + \sqrt{1+3\lambda}}{3}$$

This means that all $x_k$ are the same. Specifically, according to the constraint, $$x_k = \frac{1}{n}$$

Using this, I get that the max is $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We start with $n+1$ variables, $x_1,x_2,.....,x_n,x_{n+1}$.

Now, $x_{n+1}=1-(x_1+....+x_n)$.

So, write the sum $$f(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} x_k(1-x_k)^2$$ as follows.

$$f(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k(1-x_k)^2 +(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^2-(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^3$$.

$f(X)$ is extremum when $\vec{\nabla}f =0$.

From this we get $n$ non-linear equation of variables $x_k$ written below.

$$3{x_k}^2-4x_k+1=3(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^3-2(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^2$$

So, the right hand side is same for all $x_k, k=1,2,....,n$. Say this $c$. It's easy to see $\frac{1}{3} \leq c\leq 1$

$$3(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^3-2(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k)^2=c$$....(1)

So, the equations are $3{x_k}^2-4x_k+1-c=0$ which give the solutions like $x_k=\frac{2±\sqrt{1+3c}}{3}$.

Now from (1),

$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k=\frac{2n}{3}+m(\frac{\sqrt{1+3c}}{3})$,...(2) for some $-n \leq m \leq n$, such that $n-m$ is even.

As, $0 \leq S_n \leq 1$ we get

$2n+m\sqrt{1+3c} \leq 3$. ....(3)

As $c<1, \sqrt{1+3c}<2$, $m$ must be either $-n$ or $-(n-1)$ to satisfy (3). But, $n-(-(n-1)=2n-1$ isn't even. So, $m=-n$.

That means all $x_k=\frac{2-\sqrt{1+3c}}{3}$ , equal.

This means $f(X)$ would be maximum if $x_1=x_2=....=x_n$. But there is an additional information hidden in. That is the last $x_{n+1}$ also have to be equal with them.

$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=f(x_2,x_3,...,x_{n+1})$

as the function is symmetric. So, if we had replaced $x_1$ instead of $x_{n+1}$ that still would require $x_k$ to be equal for $k=2,3,....,n+1$.

So, $x_1=x_2=x_3=.....=x_{n+1} \rightarrow x_k=\frac{1}{n+1}$

Hence, the summation $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k(1-x_k)^2$$ along with the constraint has maximum value when $x_k=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and the maximum value is $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^2$.